# O que é o HttpHandler e HttpModule do ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

O que é o **HttpHandler** e **HttpModule** do ASP.NET?

1. Como eles funcionam?
2. E como utilizar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resumindo:

**HttpHandler** é onde a requisição é dirigida.

**HttpModule** é uma estação ao longo do caminho.

Pra mim melhor resposta retirada da fonte abaixo!

O objetivo principal e comum de **HttpHandler e HttpModule** é injetar lógica de pré-processamento antes que a solicitação ASP.NET chegue ao servidor IIS.

O ASP.NET fornece duas maneiras de injetar lógica no pipeline de solicitação;

**HttpHandlers** nos ajuda a injetar lógica de pré-processamento com base na extensão do nome do arquivo solicitado. ASP.NET usa manipuladores HTTP para implementar um monte de sua própria funcionalidade. Por exemplo, o ASP.NET usa manipuladores para processar arquivos `.aspx, .asmx e trace.axd.`
Exemplo: `feeds RSS`: Para criar um feed RSS para um site da Web, você pode criar um manipulador que emite XML formatado em RSS. Portanto, quando os usuários enviam uma solicitação ao seu site que termina em .rss, o ASP.NET chama seu manipulador para processar a solicitação.

Há três etapas envolvidas na criação do Handler:

1. Implementar IHttpHandler interface.
2. Insira o manipulador no
       arquivo web.config ou machine.config.
3. Mapeie a extensão de
       ficheiro (* .arshad) para aspnet_isapi.dll no IIS.

`IHttpHandler` interface tem `ProcessRequest` método e `IsReusable` propriedade que precisa ser implementada. `ProcessRequest`: Você deve escreve o código que produz a saída para o manipulador. `IsResuable`: Esta propriedade informa se este manipulador pode ser reutilizado ou não.

Registrando o manipulador no arquivo `web.config`:

```
<httpHandlers>
   <add verb="*" path="*.arshad" type="namespace.classname, assemblyname" />
</httpHandlers>
```

**Nota**: aqui estamos lidando com qualquer nome de arquivo com extensão **arshad**.

**HttpModule** é um processador baseado em evento para injetar lógica de pré-processamento antes que o pedido chegue ao servidor IIS. O ASP.NET usa o HttpModule para implementar lotes de sua própria funcionalidade, como autenticação e autorização, gerenciamento de sessão e cache de saída, etc.
Motor ASP.NET emite muitos eventos como a passagem do pedido através do pipeline de solicitação. Alguns desses eventos são *AuthenticateRequest, AuthorizeRequest, BeginRequest, EndRequest*. Usando HttpModule você pode escrever lógica nestes eventos. Essas lógicas são executadas conforme os eventos são disparados e antes que o pedido chegue ao IIS.

Existem duas etapas envolvidas na criação de módulos, são elas:

1. Implementar a interface IHttpModule
2. Registrar o módulo no arquivo web.config ou machine.config

Exemplo: *Segurança*: Usando o módulo HTTP, você pode executar a autenticação personalizada ou outras verificações de segurança antes que a solicitação atinja o IIS.

[FONTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449132/http-handler-vs-http-module)